# PHP - Using a constant's value to reference a data member

Tags: php, class, constants

I am trying to access one class object's data member by using a constant. I was wondering if this is possible with a syntax similar to what I am using?

When I attempt to do this in the following script I get this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM**

```
class Certificate {
    const BALANCE = 'cert_balance';

    public function __construct() {}

}

class Ticket {
    public $cert_balance = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cert_balance = 'not a chance';
        echo $this->cert_balance."<br />";
    }
}

$cert = new Certificate();

$ticket = new Ticket();

// This next code line should be equal to: $ticket->cert_balance = 'nice'; 

$ticket->$cert::BALANCE = 'nice!';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disambiguate the expression with braces. Also, prior to PHP 5.3, you need to refer to the constant via the class name, like this:

```
$ticket->{Certificate::BALANCE} = 'nice!';
```

The [PHP manual section on class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) says this

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable

So in PHP 5.3.0 and higher, this will work:

```
$ticket->{$cert::BALANCE} = 'nice!';
```

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
$ticket->{$cert::BALANCE} = 'nice';
```

So the parser knows it has to process `$cert::BALANCE` first. It seems you need [PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) for this to work. Otherwise, use the classname instead of `$cert`.

The point is that you have to put it into `{}`.

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain what is wrong with my answer. Thank you. Funny that correct answers get downvoted...